# Error: organization or project not found :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: react-native, sentry

Unable to build the release Android APK after integrating the Sentry in my react native android application.I have been getting this error.

Error: organization or project not found
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script '/TF_ReactNative_Projects/Projects/MobilityOne/node_modules/react-native-sentry/sentry.gradle' line: 126

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssetsdebugSentryUpload'.

  > Process 'command 'node_modules/sentry-cli-binary/bin/sentry-cli'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you enter organization and project name. You can get your organization and project name at the sentry.io. For example:

```
https://sentry.io/abc/my-project
```

**abc** is organization

**my-project** is project

You can edit those info at **ios/sentry.properties** and **android/sentry.properties**

Then build again!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I added more projects to my organization after configuring Sentry in my React Native App.

I edited manually `ios/sentry.properties` and `android/sentry.properties` by only changing the property

```
defaults.project=my-project-name
```